# Filter multiple columns using sqlite.swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, sqlite.swift

```
let part = self.parts.filter(self.deleteStatus == 0).order(self.id.asc)
```

Above is the query I run to get all the records from local database. Now I want to add more filters like `id==5` or `name='product'` in the filter. But the filter in sqlite.swift doesn't allow more than one expression in filter. How can I add more or filters in the filter method?

Answer (score 4):

Filters can be chained with `&&` (SQLite AND) and `||` (SQLite OR).

`self.filter(deleteStatus == 0 && id == 5 && name == "product")`

https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#filter-operators-and-functions

Answer (score -2):

The filter in Sqlite.swift does allow more than one expression; you just chain them together like this:

```
users.filter(id == 1 %% location == "Office" %% supervisor == "John")
```